# NestJS REST api - Only save data to DB after confirmation

Tags: database, rest, nestjs

I'm learning NestJS and was wondering what is the right way to implement the following scenario:

Usually in a basic CRUD API, when doing "Create" the data is sent in with a POST request and then saved into the database. I would like to implement it in a way whereby the data being sent is not committed to the database right away, rather I want to prompt the user for confirmation BEFORE saving it to the DB. I would imagine this requires 2 routes - one for passing in the data and one for confirmation. However, I do not know where to store the data while awaiting the user confirmation. Should I store it in a local variable, or is my approach completely wrong?

Regards

Comment: Prompting the user is not something your API normally does but a job for your frontend code. Implementing this in the backend is very tedious for the reason you already mentioned: where to store it? There is no good place, you need a dedicated table / row to store that unconfirmed data and then move it from there to the real table after confirmation. And you gain basically nothing: an programmer talking to the API will be annoyed by that design and a user using a frontend will never see it but the frontend will simply ask for confirmation before sending both requests, not in between.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to make 2 apis for this case. Only need to action on your front-end or some where you integrate this with an api. Follow bellow to make:

1. Make a prompt on your front-end. When users click save data then show your prompt to confirm.
2. If users click to **Confirm** then call api to save data.
3. If users click to **Cancel** then close prompt